# continuous mapping theorem for function of two variables from Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Assume we are in $\ell_{2}$ space and we have two sequences $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ with values from $\ell_{2}$ such that $||X_{n}||_{2} < c_{1}$ and $||Y_{n}||_{2} < c_{2}$ and
$$
X_{n} \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} a
$$
and
$$
Y_{n} \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} b
$$

Is this true that

$$
<X_{n},Y_{n} > \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} <a,b>?
$$

Would a.s. convergence hold for any continuous function $\ell_{2} \times \ell_{2} \to \mathbb{R}$? What is continuous mapping theorem in this case?

Comment: What does this mean, precisely? Are Xn and Yn sequences of random variables valued in ell^2?

Comment: yes, this is what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Indeed, if Xn and Yn are sequences converging to X and Y (respectively) almost surely, then (Xn,Yn) converges almost surely (in the direct sum of l2 with itself) to (X,Y). Since the inner product is continuous, this proves the claim.

Answer (score 0):

The map from $\ell^2 \times \ell^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $(x, y) \mapsto \langle x, y \rangle$ is continuous because of the estimate $|\langle x, y \rangle| \leq \|x\|\|y\|$, known as the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.